# Is there a way to take input from first Siri call with custom intents?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm intending to include a parameter input in my custom Siri intent. But I don't seem to find a way to trigger the input from the first shot "trigger word (hey Siri) + command + parameter". Spotify is implementing this. Thank u.

Comment: Did you found a way? Please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For custom intents, check 'Soup Chef' sample code : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/soup_chef_accelerating_app_interactions_with_shortcuts

As a streaming service, Spotify no doubt uses SiriKit media intents. These should be a little easier to implement:
 https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/207/
 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/media/playing_media_through_siri_shortcuts

Good luck